# Google sheets drop down with extra description - not dynamic

Tags: validation, google-sheets, dropdown

I'm trying to create a drop down picker that shows a list of values, but actually stores a related value.

The list I'm working with looks like:

```
ID   Desc
AA   An option
AB   Different option
B3   Some other option
```

So I want the user to see the description, but the value stored when they have picked one is the ID column.
I've search a lot but can only find either simple data validation or dymanic (Multiple dropdows based on a prior drop down)
My users won't remember the ID's, but by having the text descriptions they will find it easier.
Any help please?

Lots of searching for clues, but can only find either simple single column drop downs, or dynamic.

Comment: I assume that is not possible with data validation list. You can make dropdown for description then use `VLOOKUP()`, `XLOOKUP()`, `INDEX/MATCH` or `FILTER()` function retrieve ID and then use that id for other operation.

Comment: I've tried selecting both columns but google just inter mixes both in the resultant dropdown allowing the user to pick either the ID or Desc. I could do this with two columns but don't really have the horizontal space to play with.

Comment: @Harun24hr Do you have an example I could follow?

Comment: See my answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, you want to select description id `D7` cell then want to show result from `J Column` as per ID of selected description. Then Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(XLOOKUP(D7,B2:B4,A2:A4),I2:I4,J2:J4)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, would this not require 2no cells to to work? I only have room for 1. Plus every line is a different record in a table. - Here, I'll add some screen shots to explain.

Comment: Show some sample and desired result.